# How can I add a custom emoji to my Discord guild?

Tags: discord

I own a [Discord guild](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild) and would like to add custom emoji like other guild have done.

In the below screenshot, it shows some indicator emoji that I cannot type, such as `:blurple_h:`.

[image]

Comment: @ale I believe this question is referring to the Discord chat client. This question should be on topic for Web Apps, though it could arguably also belong on Super User.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Yes, it's a Discord server.

Comment: It may be worth discussing in chat or on Meta whether Discord questions belong on Super User or Web Apps. I'm personally leaning towards Super User.

Answer (score 1):

In your guild settings panel, granted you have the **Manage Emojis** permission (you are the guild owner so you have all permissions), you will have a tab named "Emoji".

[image: Emoji tab selected in guild settings panel]

From there you can upload, rename, or remove custom emoji for that guild.

[image: All 3 ways to alter server emoji]

Here is how you can do those things:

- Clicking the blurple button saying "Upload Emoji" will allow you to pick a picture and upload an emoji using that picture
- Clicking an emoji's name will allow you to rename it (2+ characters, with alphanumeric characters and underscores)
- Clicking the remove button that appears when you hover over an emoji's row will allow you to delete it

Remember, you can only have 50 emoji in a single guild.